# Validate only the scale in a decimal value (FluentValidator)

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, fluentvalidation

I am using the FluentValidator in a .NET 5 Application. I need to validate the decimal value contains only the allowed scale(allow only 2 positions)

I found the ScalePrecisionValidator but it is validating both. Any method to validate only the scale using the FluentValidator ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use scale precision validator, just set the scale to 2 and the precision to a really big number. This will be evaluated server side unless you write a client side adapter.

Working LINQPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var validator = new FooValidator();

    var foo1 = fixture.Build<Foo>().With(x => x.Bar, 1.111m).Create();
    var validationResult1 = validator.Validate(foo1);
    validationResult1.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "'Bar' must not be more than 100 digits in total, with allowance for 2 decimals. 1 digits and 3 decimals were found." });

    var foo2 = fixture.Build<Foo>().With(x => x.Bar, 1.11m).Create();
    var validationResult2 = validator.Validate(foo2);
    validationResult2.Errors.Any().Should().BeFalse();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Bar).ScalePrecision(2, 100);
    }
}
```

The regex validator should be able to do it, you'll just need a pattern to suit the desired format. This has the advantage of working client side OOTB should that be a consideration.